# Should I set LANG environment variable or use localectl set-locale?

Tags: linux, locale

Is `localectl set-locale LANG=...` a new way of setting LANG? Environment variable doesn't change this way. Or should I use both, set environment variable `LANG` and run `localectl set-locale LANG=...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variables directly is "standard".  `localctl` isn't particularly new ([about five years old](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/locale/localectl.c)), and is just a utility program that updates the related information for certain programs.  Its [documentation](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/localectl/) needs some work, but may suffice for your needs.